# How can I connect this project from local mongodb to mlab?

Tags: mongodb, angular, mlab

I clone repository from here
https://github.com/brunobrito89/udemy-node-angular2.git
by default this project for local mongodb:

```
mongoose.connect('localhost:27017/node-angular');
```

but
I would like use mlab.
How can I connect to mlab this project??

Answer (score 0):

Should be as simple as creating a plan with mLab (http://docs.mlab.com/subscriptions/), then plugging the connection string for your mLab database into `mongoose.connect()` (http://docs.mlab.com/connecting/)